# Removed configuration option (notablescan) in MongoDB 2.6 config file

Tags: mongodb

The configuration file format was changed in the latest (2.6) version of `MongoDB` into a `YAML` based format.

Apparently the new format removed some configuration options, `notablescan` in my case.

Is there a way to set it in the new format? Or must I stay with the 2.4 version one?

[v2.6 Configuration File Options](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/)
[v2.4 Configuration File Options](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `notablescan` in the new format with [setParameter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#setParameter) call. For example:

```
setParameter:
    notablescan: 1
```

Comment: Actually it's `setParameter: 
    notablescan: 1` (new line + tab)

Comment: Great! Also updated the syntax in the answer -- please correct me if its still invalid.

Comment: The example quoted in the console documentation is `db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand( { setParameter: 1, notablescan: 1 } )` however, it doesn't seem clear to me what this does. Is it perDb? Per server?

Comment: How do you do this ^^ on a sharded server? It says you can't do it with mongos?